# apt-get update getting 400 URI Failure message

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-11.04

I have setup my ubuntu vps recently, but suddenly I keep getting this error message when I try to do apt-get update

> E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message

I have try to comment out 2 by 2 in my source list and do the apt-get update, no matter how I still getting the same error.

Comment: This means that the servers you're attempting to access, or a proxy between you and the server receives a bad request.  How's your luck if you try to access the server with curl?

Comment: do you mean I should test the very line of url in the apt source by curl ?

Comment: That is what I mean, yes.

Answer (score 3):

If you share your /etc/apt/sources.list we can probably try to help you.

Otherwise, I wrote a tool to debug this (assumes you have ruby and rubygems installed):

```
server# gem install apt-repair-sources
...
server# apt-repair-sources
...
```

This should tell you which lines in your sources are off. I'm guessing it's something like, 11.04 was moved from release.ubuntu.com to archive.ubuntu.com. Or something. Or maybe a mirror you are using is down.

Answer (score 2):

it seem like is locale problem after i remove some locale setting, it work again.